# Tentando fazer busca com id especifico em um periodo

Tags: c#, sql, hql

Estou tentando pegar um carro especifico entre datas, pois ele funciona em períodos, mais preciso pegar o ID do elemento, não sei se teria que aplicar alguma outra consulta ou incluir na mesma, o banco que eu utilizo é o SQL, caso haja duvida

**Quero fazer seria do seguinte modo:**

```
 SELECT * FROM Abastecimento a WHERE NumCarroId = 1013 AND DtAbastecido BETWEEN '2017-07-01'AND '2017-07-30';
```

Sendo que no `1013` eu queria que ele pegasse da textbox da minha view

**Minha HQL me retorna o período de data:**

```
    public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaPeriodo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal)
        {
            string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido BETWEEN :dataInicial AND :dataFinal";
            IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
                .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
                .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal);
            return query.List<Abastecimento>();
        }
```

E minha controller que utiliza essa consulta:

```
    public ActionResult AbastecimentoPeriodo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal, int? pagina, Boolean? gerarPDF, AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
        {
            var data = ckm.ConsultaPeriodo(dataInicio,dataFinal);
            ViewBag.dataInicio = dataInicio;
            ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFinal;
            var periodo = data.Where(i => i.DtAbastecido >= dataInicio && i.DtAbastecido <= dataFinal).OrderBy(p => p.DtAbastecido).ToList<Abastecimento>();
            int paginaQdteRegistros = 25;
            int paginaNumeroNavegacao = (pagina ?? 1);
            return View(data.ToPagedList(paginaNumeroNavegacao, paginaQdteRegistros));
        }
```

Comment: já tentou usar o HAVING ? qual o banco ?
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: não tentei ainda, o banco é SQL, mas na hora da consulta eu uso o LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, fiz alguns teste em SQL em minha consulta ficou assim

**Minha HQL:**

```
 public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaPeriodo(int carro, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a WHERE NumCarroId = :carro AND a.DtAbastecido BETWEEN :dataInicial AND :dataFinal";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
            .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
            .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal)
            .SetParameter("carro", carro);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }
```

**E meu controller:**

```
public ActionResult AbastecimentoPeriodo(int carro, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal, int? pagina, Boolean? gerarPDF, AbastecimentoModel viewModel)
    {

        var data = ckm.ConsultaPeriodo(carro,dataInicio,dataFinal);
        ViewBag.dataInicio = dataInicio;
        ViewBag.carro = carro;
        ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFinal;

        var periodo = data.OrderBy(p => p.DtAbastecido).ToList<Abastecimento>();

        int paginaQdteRegistros = 25;
        int paginaNumeroNavegacao = (pagina ?? 1);
        return View(data.ToPagedList(paginaNumeroNavegacao, paginaQdteRegistros));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como não sabemos a estrutura do seu banco de dados, não consigo te dizer exatamente a consulta a ser feita, mas via de regra, basta adicionar no where do select um "AND" e o Id do carro ou algo do tipo, que possa identificar o carro.